# PowerShell genera corruptos los ficheros

Tags: nodejs, git, powershell

llevo unos dias haciendo uso de unos paquetes de Node.js para gestionar mejor Git y los commits, estos son `commitlint` y `husky`, desde la pagina oficil hay un tutorial muy sencillo para instalar y utilizar. [Pagina oficial para la guia](https://commitlint.js.org/#/guides-local-setup?id=install-commitlint).

Este comando es el necesario para generar un fichero de configuracion.

```sh
echo "module.exports = {extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional']};" > commitlint.config.js
```

Mi problema llega cuando me fijo que al utilizar la PowerShell integrada de VS Code este fichero se genera normal pero al intentar crear un commit me salta un error.

Nada mas miren la parte donde se ve los signos "��m", diciendo que el error esta al inicio del fichero, justo antes del "module.exports" que se crea en el fichero, pero es que antes no hay nada de nada.

```sh
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba git action> git commit -m "feat:prueba"

C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba git action\commitlint.config.js:1
��m

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token...
```

Dicho error pasa cuando creo dicho fichero con PowerShell, pero esto no sucede cuando el fichero es creado desde la Git bash que integra VS Code con Git, y eso es lo que no entiendo. Despues de varias horas de probar me di cuanta de que si creas el mismo fichero e instruccion sin comandos tambien esta todo bien, y creo que que el problema lo genera la PowerShell al crear el fichero. Es como si la Shell de windows creara algun artefacto raro al inicio.

Tambien me fije que si ejecutas el mismo comando para crear el fichero, uno con PowerShell y otro con Git Bash, el fichero que crea PowerShell pesa bastante mas que el de Git Bash, hablamos de Kb que es muy poco, pero siendo exatamente el mismo fichero, el de PowerShell pesa mas del doble que el otro, siendo el de Git bash de 67Kb y el de PowerShell 137Kb.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el contenido del archivo creado? He trabajado con ambas librerías y te puedo decir que no importa cómo crees el archivo, al ser de configuración solo lo harás una vez, y no tiene que ser forzosamente a través de un `echo`.

Comment: Aqui tienes @ricardo-dlc, se que no es necesario pero me gustaria entender, y si puedo resolver, porque la powershell me da ese problema porque hace tan solo un dia me funcionaba perfectamente. El contenido del fichero es: module.exports = {extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional']};

Comment: Bueno, por lo que veo entonces el archivo parece estar ok. Por lo que posiblemente pueda ser un problema con PowerShell. Investigaré un poco, si tengo alguna novedad comparto.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc gracias amigo, yo tambien seguire mirando, un saludo desde.

Comment: Tal vez tenga que ver con [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8). Prueba creando el archivo en powershell con `echo "module.exports = {extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional']};" | out-file commitlint.config.js -encoding utf8`

Comment: Nunca habria pensado la idea del encodig, no suelo suar la powerShell y estos problemas se me hacen mucha bola alguna vez jajaja, gacias @braver, te lo agradezco :D